# How to get upper str this case

Tags: uppercase

I want to get upper"T"..
how to get upper string!

```
str = "Test Version"

print(str.upper())
print(str[3])
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking.
But from context I am guessing you would like to make the second non-capitalised "t" in the string uppercase. I'm also going to assume you are using python 3 given your use of upper().

If you just want to get the "t" (and not change the string itself):
`upper_T = str[3].upper()`

If you want to create a string from the original you may be running into the fact that [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) in python are [immutable](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747). You therefore must create a new string.

One way do this:

```
str2 = list(str)
str2[3] = str[3].upper()
str2 = ''.join(str2)
```